# Bookdown Citation Order using Medical Numbering Format

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

I am using the bookdown package to write an academic paper. It is using numbered citations, where the citations are given a superscripted number in the text, which refers to an endnote with the citation. The citations are numbered in order, starting from 1 where the footnote first occurs.

I have citations in a table. I render this table in a R code chunk using *flextable* and have *flextable* output markdown using as a chunk option, *render="as.is"*. This allows me to reference citations with [@reference] and have this output to PDF or HTML without issues.

The problem I'm having is that **the citations in the table are being numbered first, and then the citations in text.** So, even though the table is at the end of the document, the citation in the table is numbered "1".

Is there a way to have the citation numbers generated for the table after the document citations numbers are generated?

This is tricky to create reproducible code, but here's the Markdown file and a screenshot of what this is producing. Note how the superscript 1 is in the table, after superscript 2.

````
---
title: "A Minimal Book Example"
author: "John Doe"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
description: |
  Test
link-citations: yes
github-repo: rstudio/bookdown-demo
csl: american-medical-association.csl
---

# About

This is a *sample* book written in **Markdown** [@bookdown2016].

```{r, render="as.is"}
library(flextable)
library("ftExtra")
data("mtcars")
mtcars[1,1] = "A REFERENCE [@R-knitr]"
mtcars |> flextable() |> colformat_md()
```
````

[image]

Comment: Do you need `flextable` for other reasons? Your example works with `mtcars |> knitr::kable()` instead of `mtcars |> flextable() |> colformat_md()`.